# PC needs to reboot several times before it shows image

Tags: boot, graphics-card, display, motherboard

Computer specs are:

- AMD Ryzen 5 1600x
- MSI B350M GAMING PRO
- Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB
- 8GB HyperX Fury 2400Mhz

I've facing this problem for some time and I need help figuring out what is causing it.

When I try to turn on the computer, it 95% of the time will not show image, but it will actually make it into the OS (I've managed to play a song on Spotify without display).

Then to make it display something I reboot it several times after the mouse lights up (it's the point that if the pc don't show image it will not anymore), sometimes I reboot like 20+ times before it shows display.

When it finally shows image, everything is ok, the pc can stay on for weeks (its what i am doing xd) without issues, its possible to play games, other GPU demanding tasks, CPU demanding tasks, without an issue.

I dont know if this is a GPU problem, maybe a HDMI port problem, I tested with other monitor but only HDMIs monitors.

Oh, and if the windows go to sleep mode it never comes back, then this made me think about some kind of HDMI output problem. On the other hand, sometimes the computer boots on weird resolutions, 800*600, etc, and if I go into BIOS the language is changed to Chinese or some other weird letter symbols hehe, this made me think of motherboard problem.

Well that's it. I need help solving this problem to maybe change the right part.

Thanks [ ]

Comment: Start by updating UEFI.

Comment: BIOS is at the latest version

Comment: Please contact tech support.